Get signature from HSM
I'd like to use an HSM to sign my Hedera transactions but I get an error. In order to create a repeatable example I tried this
package com.managination;

import com.hedera.hashgraph.sdk.*;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.Signer;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Ed25519PublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.Ed25519Signer;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;


public class HederaTransactionWithHSM {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws PrecheckStatusException, TimeoutException, CryptoException, ReceiptStatusException {
      new HederaTransactionWithHSM().testSigner();
   }

   public void testSigner() throws PrecheckStatusException, TimeoutException, CryptoException, ReceiptStatusException {
      PrivateKey fundedPrivateKey = PrivateKey.fromStringED25519(MY_PRIVATE_KEY);
      Client client = Client.forTestnet();
      AccountId fundedAccountId = AccountId.fromString("0.0.3672483");
      client.setOperator(fundedAccountId, fundedPrivateKey);

      PrivateKey emptyPrivateKey = PrivateKey.generateED25519();
      PublicKey publicKey = emptyPrivateKey.getPublicKey();
      TransactionResponse newAccountCreateTX = new AccountCreateTransaction()
            .setKey(publicKey)
            .setInitialBalance(Hbar.from(0))
            .execute(client);

      client.setOperator(newAccountCreateTX.getReceipt(client).accountId, emptyPrivateKey);

      // Create a transaction that needs to be signed with the fundedPrivateKey
      assert client.getOperatorAccountId() != null;
      TransferTransaction transaction = new TransferTransaction()
            .addHbarTransfer(client.getOperatorAccountId(), Hbar.from(10))
            .addHbarTransfer(fundedAccountId, Hbar.from(-10))
            .setTransactionId(TransactionId.generate(fundedAccountId))
            .freezeWith(client)
//            .sign(fundedPrivateKey)
            .sign(emptyPrivateKey);
      
      // Get the transaction hash
      byte[] transactionHash = transaction.getTransactionHash();
      
      // Add the signature to the transaction
      transaction.addSignature(fundedPrivateKey.getPublicKey(), this.sign(transactionHash, fundedPrivateKey));

      // Execute the transaction
      TransactionResponse response = transaction.execute(client);
      TransactionId transactionId = response.transactionId;
      System.out.println("Transaction ID: " + transactionId);
   }

   public byte[] sign(byte[] message, PrivateKey hederaPrivateKey) throws CryptoException {
      Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters privateKeyParameters = new Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters(hederaPrivateKey.toBytes(), 0);

      // Obtain the corresponding public key from the private key
      Ed25519PublicKeyParameters publicKeyParameters = privateKeyParameters.generatePublicKey();

      // Create an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair from the private and public key parameters
      AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(publicKeyParameters, privateKeyParameters);

      // Extract the keys
      AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate(); // private key
      AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = keyPair.getPublic(); // public key

      // sign a simple message
      Signer signer = new Ed25519Signer();
      signer.init(true, privateKey);
      signer.update(message, 0, message.length);
      byte[] signature = signer.generateSignature(); // Signature!!!

      // now let's verify the signature
      signer.init(false, publicKey);
      signer.update(message, 0, message.length);
      boolean isVerified = signer.verifySignature(signature); // should be true!!

      System.out.println("Signature of Verification Result: " + isVerified);
      return signature;
   }
}

I know this works because if I replace the my custom signing function with the default Hedera function the transaction is executed just fine.
